# When pressing on spacebar the previous clicked button gets clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a game that throws bombs when pressing the **spacebar** and the problem is that when I press this key the game ends, because it interprets pressing the spacebar to click the previously clicked button **Start Game** which changes to **End Game** once the game starts.

How can I solve this issue? Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
var spacebar = false, btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('test') })

// ---- Spacebar functionality ----
function handleKeyDown(e){
  e.keyCode === 32 ? spacebar = true : null
}
function handleKeyUp(e){
  e.keyCode === 32 ? spacebar = false : null
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false)
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp, false)
```

```html
1) Click the button
<br>
2) Now without clicking press the spacebar
<br><br>
<button id="btn">Click me to console log</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `document.activeElement.blur();` and lost the focus on the button.

```js
var spacebar = false, btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  console.log('test');

  document.activeElement.blur(); //<----- Here my edit

})

// ---- Spacebar functionality ----
function handleKeyDown(e){
  e.keyCode === 32 ? spacebar = true : null
}
function handleKeyUp(e){
  e.keyCode === 32 ? spacebar = false : null
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false)
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp, false)
```

```html
1) Click the button
<br>
2) Now without clicking press the spacebar
<br><br>
<button id="btn">Click me to console log</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by removing button response to the 'keyup' event

```
<button id="btn" onkeyup="event.preventDefault()">Click me to console log</button>
```